# compiling a dynamic link library (DLL) on windows with cl.exe and powershell but without CMake, MSBuild or Visual Studio

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I want to understand how to compile and link dynamic link-libraries work on Windows. I'd typically use CMake for this type of task, but I want to understand how I could achieve it without CMake (or any other build system). I am looking for raw commands to type into powershell.

On UNIX, this is rather straightforward, but on Windows I seem to be hitting a wall and there doesn't seem to be any good resources, at least non that I could find in the last coupel of days (neither here on stackoverflow nor anywhere else). There are a few solution that come close to my problem, but they were not able to clarify all questions I had so hence me asking this question here.

I have coded up a simple toy project that should help to clarify where I am having issues.

The project structure is as follows:

```bash
root
├── build
├── lib
│   ├── myMathLib.h
│   └── myMathLib.cpp
├── main.cpp
└── compileAndRun.bat
```

Within the `lib` folder, I have the following files and their content:

```cpp
// myMathLib.h
#pragma once

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
  #ifdef COMPILED
    #define API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#endif

extern "C" {

class MyMathLib {
public:
  API int add(int a, int b);
};

}
```

```cpp
// myMathLib.cpp
#include "lib/myMathLib.h"

int MyMathLib::add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

The main file is simply calling this function:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "lib/myMathLib.h"

int main() {
  MyMathLib math;
  std::cout << "2 + 3 = " << math.add(2, 3) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

my `compileAndRun.bat` file looks liek the following

```
@echo off

del /q build
mkdir build

REM compile source files into object code
cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Od /I. /DCOMPILED lib/myMathLib.cpp /Fobuild\myMathLib.obj
cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Od /I. main.cpp /Fobuild\main.obj

REM link object files into dynamic library
link /nologo /DLL /OUT:build\libMyMath.dll build\myMathLib.obj

REM compile main function and link library into executable
cl /nologo /EHsc /Od /I. build\main.obj /Fe:build\dynamicLibExample.exe /link /DLL /LIBPATH:build build\libMyMath.dll 

REM remove object files
del build\*.obj

REM run
echo Running dynamic library example
build\dynamicLibExample.exe
```

In this script, I am able to compile the source files and even create the `libMyMath.dll` file within the `build` folder. However, when I try to link my `main.obj` file against the dynamic library (line 14), I am getting a compiler error of `build\libMyMath.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2F8` and I am unable to progress past this point, so my question is how I can link this DLL file now against my `main.cpp` file.

One additional question: Do I need `extern "C"` here if I am only planning to use this code in C++ codebases? I'd argue name mangling is not an issue so I could probably drop it but I see everyone else doing it, but I suppose it is just to make it available for C as well.

And one clarification: I understand that the `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` are only required for windows platforms, but from what I have read I could get rid of them and provide a `*.def` file. It seems this is not the preferred method from what I have read, but if someone could show (again, for educational purposes) how I could achieve a library code without the `#pragma`s and with a `*.def` file instead, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I know where you are coming from.  Microsoft doesn't do a good job of publishing a complete set of compiler options.  Compiler options that existed in the early 1990's are still available but no longer documented.  See following for compiler options : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170

Comment: Great, it's not just me then! Thanks for the link, couldn't find this on learn.microsoft.com, and I have checked a few of their sites.

Comment: Where you able to find a complete solution? I started to look at the subject for programming in C and was having problems with Windows too.
Thanks to this question answer I was able to create the executable BUT windows give me "This app can't run on your PC"

Comment: yes, I got the same error message, due to a superfluous /DLL flag. this was solved in another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77596252/after-compiling-c-with-dll-on-windows-im-getting-this-app-cant-run-on-your

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you link the DLL, the import library libMyMath.lib is created. This library has the same .lib extension as a static library, but it doesn't contain the code of the functions. There are only function stubs that call the implementation in the DLL.

You must link with the LIB instead of the DLL, when you build the EXE file:

```
cl /nologo /EHsc /Od /I. build\main.obj /Fe"build\dynamicLibExample.exe" /link /DLL /LIBPATH:build build\libMyMath.lib
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked (I think, I can generate the *.exe file but I am getting an access denied error, and can't execute it but at least I made some progress, thanks!). It's weird, but I guess on Windows everything is different (for a UNIX developer ...)