# After compiling c++ with DLL on windows, I'm getting "This app can't run on your PC" error on windows" but not for static libraries

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, dll, execution

### Problem statement

There are quite a few questions relating to the "This app can't run on your PC" and I have a feeling I went through most of them here on SO, but none of the solutions worked so I am asking here a separate question.

I have a very simple c++ example that I want to compile on Windows 11 with Microsoft's cl compiler (Version 19.37.32825, x64). The project consists of a `main.cpp` file, as well as a class that I want to compile into a dynamic link library (DLL). I am able to compile and execute the the code into a static/dynamic library on UNIX (ubuntu to be precise) but I am only getting the static library to work on Windows. I can still get the dynamic link library to compile and generate an *.exe file that links against that library, but I can't run the executable, I am always getting the following error when running my *.exe file:

[image]

The console prints "Access is denied." as well.

### Things I have already tried but aren't working

1. Loading the vcvarsall.bat file through PowerShell with different architecture options, e.g. `cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64`. Here, i have tried all available architectures, e.g. `x86 | amd64 | x86_amd64 | x86_arm | x86_arm64 | amd64_x86 | amd64_arm | amd64_arm64` just to be sure. This was to ensure I compiled the code in either 32/64 bit consistently. This did not help.
2. Deactivate my anti-virus completely (I am using Avast). I have also added the `root` folder to my list of exception folders, i.e. folders for AVAST not to scan, just to be sure. Checked in Windows Defender as well but no options are available to add folder exceptions, presumably because AVAST is installed and managing this. Checked the logs of AVAST as well, and the quarantine section, nothing in here that looks suspicious.
3. Run Powershell with admin rights.
4. Run the exe directly, run it in compatibility mode (Windows 8), as well as running the compatibility mode troubleshooter.
5. Reboot in safe mode (command line) and execute the *.exe directly from the command line, still not working (just printing "Access is denied." to the console).
6. Checked the event viewer on Windows, no suspicious entries here either.
7. Activate developer mode on Windows

I am able to compile and run the code if I compile the library into a static library, not a dynamic, i.e. DLL, library. The issue only arises when I am trying to compile and link against the DLL version of the library.

Any suggestions that will help to overcome this error would be appreciated!

### Complete code and project structure for reproducibility

Not that I think it matters too much, but I give my code here for completeness. This is my project structure:

```bash
root
├── build
├── lib
│   ├── myMathLib.h
│   └── myMathLib.cpp
├── main.cpp
└── compileAndRun.bat
```

This is the content of the following files:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "lib/myMathLib.h"

int main() {
  MyMathLib math;
  std::cout << "2 + 3 = " << math.add(2, 3) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// myMathLib.h
#pragma once

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
  #ifdef COMPILED
    #define API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#endif

class MyMathLib {
public:
  API int add(int a, int b);
};
```

```cpp
// myMathLib.cpp
#include "lib/myMathLib.h"

int MyMathLib::add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

```
REM compileAndBuild.bat
@echo off

del /q build
mkdir build

REM compile source files into object code
cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Od /I. /DCOMPILED lib/myMathLib.cpp /Fobuild\myMathLib.obj
cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Od /I. main.cpp /Fobuild\main.obj

REM link object files into dynamic library
link /nologo /DLL /OUT:build\libMyMath.dll build\myMathLib.obj

REM compile main function and link library into executable
cl /nologo /EHsc /Od /I. build\main.obj /Fe:build\dynamicLibExample.exe /link /DLL /LIBPATH:build build\libMyMath.lib

REM remove object files
del build\*.obj

REM run
echo Running dynamic library example
build\dynamicLibExample.exe
```

It's worth pointing out that for the static library to work I have to modify the `myMathLib.h` file and essentially set the `API` macro to an empty string (i.e. remove the `__declspec(dllimport|dllexport)` statements.

Usually, I would use CMake, but I am interested to learn which commands I need to use if I want to manually provide the inputs into Powershell.

Comment: The `/DLL` is to build a DLL, it must not be set when you produce the exe file.

Comment: You are running a Matlab dll.  You either need Matlab installed or the Correct version of the Runtime library.  The version of the Runtime library must be the same version that was used to compile the dll in Matlab.

Comment: thanks @dalfaB, no idea how that flag sneaked in but that did the job!